# How to open and close fragment,clicking on the same button in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

how to open and close fragment while clicking on same button . Just like amazon filter button.
when we click first time fragment should apper and then we click on that button again fragment should disapper.

business activity java file

```
public class business extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView t1, t2;
Button hello;
boolean flag = false;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_business);
    hello = findViewById(R.id.hello);
    t1=findViewById(R.id.text1);
    t2=findViewById(R.id.textt2);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    hello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            BusinessSort businessSort = new BusinessSort();
            fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            if (flag) {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(businessSort);
                flag=false;
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frgmCont, businessSort);
                flag=true;
            }
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

}


public void f1(String s1, String s2) {
    t1.setText(s1);
    t2.setText(s2);
}
```

}

activity_business.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".business"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/businessLinearLayout">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="edit1"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="edit2"
    android:id="@+id/textt2"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frgmCont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Fagment file BusinessSort.java

```
public class BusinessSort extends Fragment {

EditText editText1,editText2;
Button submit;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_sort, container, false);
    editText1=view.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    editText2=view.findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    submit=view.findViewById(R.id.businessfragment_submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String s1 = editText1.getText().toString();
            String s2 = editText2.getText().toString();
            business business = (com.example.project.business) getActivity();
            business.f1(s1,s2);

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

fragment_business_sort.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".BusinessSort"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/businessfragment_submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SUBMIT"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the fragment.

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frgmCont, businessSort);
 flag = true;
```

I hope the code is mostly similar to my approach so let me know if the problem still persists so that I will look into it deeper.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean fragmentState = false;

onClick(){
    if(fragmentState){
          fragmentState = false;
          getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
          remove(SomeFragment.this).commit();
    }
    else{
         fragmentState = true;
         Fragment someFragment = new SomeFragment(); 
         FragmentTransaction transaction = 
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment );
         transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
         transaction.commit(); 
    }
}
```

Please make sure that your button is not a part of that fragment.
You need to save the state of the fragment.